# Auto timestamp update not working in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, annotations

HI,

My POJO class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seed")
public class SeedUrl {

    @Id
    SeedUrlPrimaryKey primaryKey = new SeedUrlPrimaryKey();

     @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column
    private Date lastUpdated;



    public SeedUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }
    public SeedUrl(){}

    public SeedUrlPrimaryKey getPrimaryKey() {
        return primaryKey;
    }

    public void setPrimaryKey(SeedUrlPrimaryKey primaryKey) {
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    }


    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void onLastUpdated() {
        this.lastUpdated = new Date();
    }
}
```

I want to update the same column either on insert or update ..

I am saving the object as follows:

```
SeedUrlPrimaryKey primaryKey = new SeedUrlPrimaryKey();
            primaryKey.setSeedId("111121123");
            seedUrl.setPrimaryKey(primaryKey);
            session.save(seedUrl);
                    session.getTransaction().commit()
```

But in the Database the value of lastUpdated is coming as null..
In DB the column is declared as TIMESTAMP.
Where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Hibernate via `Session` interface, JPA callback methods (`@PrePersist`, etc) don't work. You can use [Hibernate listeners](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/events.html#objectstate-events) instead.